# Removing an object from a list in a foreach loop of that list

Tags: c#

I have made a method that eliminates any replicates of the same `string` in a List.

now, the problem is that it gives me this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

I read in the internet, and i think that the problem is the i am removing an object from the list inside the `foreach` loop of the list.

```
    foreach (string r in list)
    {
        int numberOfAppearance=0;
        foreach (string rs in list)
        {
            if (r == rs && numberOfAppearance> 0)
                list.Remove(rs);
            else
                numberOfAppearance++;
        }
    }
```

How can i fix the method? Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you need to do this yourself, or could you just use `list = list.Distinct().ToList()`? Or are you trying to remove *all* occurrences of any items that have duplicates? (So should a list of { "a", "b", "c", "b" } end up as { "a", "b", "c" } or just { "a", "c" }?)

Comment: ohhh there is a method that does that?!, i guess that would work, i dont need to do this myself. Thanks

Comment: Well it depends on what you want the result to be. Using `Distinct` will give {"a", "b", "c"} in this case.

Comment: thats what i need, so it will do

Comment: Okay. I'll add an answer with a few points then...

Comment: is there a method that does that to an array? because right now i am converting it to a list and then back to an array

Comment: You can't modify the list when you are itterating over it. You have to create a new one, and override afterwards.

Comment: @Cooper there is both `ToList` and `ToArray` in Linq. I think Jon will add that to his answer as well :)

Comment: @JonSkeet if i want to use that on an array, to do it like this?:
        array = array.Distinct().ToArray();

Comment: @Cooper: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, as noted in comments, LINQ has got you covered here:

```
list = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

It's *well* worth looking into LINQ for data operations - it can make things much simpler.

As for what's wrong with your current code - there are a couple of things:

Firstly, you're removing by *item* rather than by index, which will remove the first occurrence of that item, not the one you're actually looking at

Secondly, if you modify a list while you're iterating over it, you *will* get precisely the exception you've seen. From the docs for `List<T>.GetEnumerator`:

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably invalidated and its behavior is undefined.

You can get around this by iterating by *index* rather than using a `foreach` loop, but if you're removing an item you need to remember that everything below that will move up one element. So either you need to iterate *backwards* to remove items, or you need to remember to decrement the index.

Here's an approach which uses iterating by index *forwards* in terms of what we're looking at, but *backwards* in terms of looking for duplicates - stopping when we get to the index we're looking at. Note that this is still O(N<sup>2</sup>) - it's not as efficient as using `Distinct`:

```
// We're looking for duplicates *after* list[i], so we don't need to go as far
// as i being the very last element: there aren't any elements after it to be
// duplicates. (We could easily still just use list.Count, and the loop for j
// would just have 0 iterations.)
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
{
    // Go backwards from the end, looking for duplicates of list[i]
    for (int j = list.Count - 1; j > i; j--)
    {
        if (list[j] == list[i])
        {
            list.RemoveAt(j);
        }
    }
}
```

(For more details on `Distinct`, see my [Edulinq post on it](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-14-distinct.aspx).)

Comment: @Default: We're looking for elements *after* `list[i]` - so when `i` is at the end of the list, there can't *be* any later duplicates. In your example, the second `"a"` would have been removed when `i` was 0.

Answer (score 1):

As many people point out, you can use the `Distinct` method for your particular problem.

However, the problem you are actually having is that you are trying to modify the list when you iterate over it, which will not end well.

```
//This will not work.
foreach (string rs in list)
{
    if (some_test)
    {
        list.Remove(rs); //Because of this line.
    }
}
```

If you want do do something similar to this you need to find a way around this problem. Often it involves making a new array.

For this examle you can do the following

```
List newList = new ArrayList();
foreach (string rs in list)
{
    if (!some_test)
    {
        newList.add(rs);
    }
}
```

If you really want to create a "remove duplicates" method I would have done it in this fashion (pseudocode):

```
Hash cache_hash = new Hash(default false)
List new_list = new List
foreach string s in list
{
    if not cache_hash[s]
    {
        new_list.add(s)
        cache_hash[s] = true
    }
}

list = new_list
```

This method is `Ω(N)` , so it is fairly fast on even large lists.